# Camel CXFRS mapping of exceptions for JAXRS provider

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I have a route very similar to the example code at camel\examples\camel-example-cxf\src\main\java\org\apache\camel\example\cxf\jaxrs (in the camel git project).

So I have a route like:

```
   public void configure() {
         from(REST_ENDPOINT_URI)
             .process(new MappingProcessor(new MyImpl()));
     }

// Mapping the request to object's invocation
private static class MappingProcessor implements Processor {

    private Class<?> beanClass;
    private Object instance;

    public MappingProcessor(Object obj) {
        beanClass = obj.getClass();
        instance = obj;
    }

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String operationName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, String.class);
        Method method = findMethod(operationName, exchange.getIn().getBody(Object[].class));
        try {
            Object response = method.invoke(instance, exchange.getIn().getBody(Object[].class));
            exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
        }  catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw (Exception)e.getCause();
        }
    }

    private Method findMethod(String operationName, Object[] parameters) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {            
        return beanClass.getMethod(operationName, getParameterTypes(parameters));
    }

    private Class<?>[] getParameterTypes(Object[] parameters) {
        if (parameters == null) {
            return new Class[0];
        }
        Class<?>[] answer = new Class[parameters.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (Object object : parameters) {
            answer[i] = object.getClass();
            i++;
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

I have a resource that just has a PUT operation on it, and within that I throw WebApplicationExceptions for various reasons, eg 404 when resource not found, i.e:

```
    Response r = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Resource not found").build();

    throw new WebApplicationException(r);
```

Within a junit CXF test this works fine. But when I have the camel route above up and running and fire in a PUT request with curl, for some reason I still get a 200 OK response, even though I definitely throw the 404.

Any ideas why this is? Here is the stacktrace that camel throws (and just to clarify, I am not creating any null pointer exception):

```
17:14:09,608  WARN org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils:443 doLog() - Interceptor for {http://REST.myhost.com/}MyImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1.cacheInput(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:273)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.cacheInput(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:529)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.flushHeaders(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:541)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.flushHeaders(JettyHTTPDestination.java:380)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.flushHeaders(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:534)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:711)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.EncodingXmlWriter.flushBuffer(EncodingXmlWriter.java:697)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.EncodingXmlWriter.flush(EncodingXmlWriter.java:171)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:259)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.interceptor.XMLFaultOutInterceptor.handleMessage(XMLFaultOutInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:331)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:355)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:319)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1010)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**EDIT:**
Even if I don't throw any exception, ie my PUT handler just returns a 200 OK and no exception is thrown, I still get the same stack trace once control has left the above processor.

Comment: And just to add, the line in the processor:                                     catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw (Exception)e.getCause();
        }                                                           is catching the WebApplicationException and rethrowing it.

Comment: Looking in the AbstractHTTPDestination.java code, perhaps this is a web.xml thing? I thought the whole point of camel in this situation was to handle all of that side of things.

Comment: +1 for the `MappingProcessor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was running in tomcat BTW. I changed my url to be:

```
    from("cxfrs:/rest" +       
    "?resourceClasses=org.apache.camel.example.cxf.jaxrs.resources.BookStoreImpl").
```

rather than:

```
    from("cxfrs:/http://localhost:9090/rest" + 
    "?resourceClasses=org.apache.camel.example.cxf.jaxrs.resources.BookStoreImpl").
```

then accessed it via port 8080.